# UIView animate frame of ImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview, frame

I'm trying to add an animation to a UIImageView when a button is tapped. When the button is tapped I want the imageView to move to the right at the same time as it is increasing in size. I have tried this code, but the imageView aren't animation correct.

```
- (IBAction)bA:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    CGRect frame = imageView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x + 30;
    frame.size.hight = frame.size.hight + 20;
    frame.size.width = frame.size.width + 20;
    imageView.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This code makes the imageView move little to the right, then back again. Wierd behavior, what should I do to animate both size and origin at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've got Autolayout turned on. With Autolayout, you cannot change the frame of something, because layout comes along and changes it back again.

Either turn Autolayout off, or else animate by changing the *constraints* of this view instead of its frame.

Comment: Here is the section of my book about this problem: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_animation_and_autolayout

Comment: Is it possible to turn off Autolayout on one specific View Controller?

Comment: If you are using a nib/xib, you can turn off Autolayout for that nib. Alternatively, you can turn off Autolayout just for this image view by saying `imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO`.

Comment: Here is the section of my book about Autolayout: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_autolayout

Comment: I tried to set `imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` right before I set the new frame, but it didn't change anything. The animation was performed on the same wrong way. What about all the other autolayout objects that is linked to the imageView, are they affecting the animation?

Comment: Yes, probably. Sorry about that. - If you don't want to turn Autolayout off for the entire nib/storyboard, perhaps the best solution is to animate the constraints as I suggested earlier (or change the constraints as part of the animation). Autolayout makes animation a lot more complicated than it used to be; they are enemies to each other. In my view this is the biggest problem with iOS 6.